# Matlab; How to specify Coupon frequency for Interest Rate Swap

Tags: interest-rates, fixed-income, pricing, swaps, matlab

I'm trying to price an interest rate swap and would like to change the default coupon payment frequency from 1 a year to 2 or 4 a year. I'm using

```
Price = swapbyzero(RateSpec, LegRate, i, Maturity, 'Principal', Principal);
```

and tried

```
Price = swapbyzero(RateSpec, LegRate, i, Maturity, 'Principal', Principal,'Period',2);
```

where 'Period' is a valid option when pricing bond using

```
prbyzero
```

I'm using matlab 2013a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name-Value pair option 'LegReset' [n n] where n is the frequency

Comment: Is this the answer?

Comment: Question was also asked on Stack Overflow, and this was the answer accepted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764495/matlab-how-to-specify-coupon-frequency-for-interest-rate-swap?utm_source=feedly

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is supported by MatLab (I use Java to do such stuff :-).

But in case you do not find a solution from the swapbyzero function you mentioned I can suggest a workaround:

- Value a swap with the annual fix frequence.

Given that it is a payer swap (pays the fixed leg), correct the value by:

- Substract the value of an annual fix coupon bond and
- Add the value of the desired frequence fix coupon bond.

PS: Note that the MatLab function is likely not appropriate to value a swap in a "realistic" way, since it looks like multi-curve (OIS discounting) is not considered here (I wonder if term structure is considered?), see also [Rationale for OIS discounting for collateralized derivatives?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/723/rationale-for-ois-discounting-for-collateralized-derivatives/4919#4919)